# Solve the i.v.p DE

Tags: differential-forms

Solve the i.v.p $y^{(4)}-y'''=0 , y(0)=0, y'(0)=0, y"(0)=0, y"'(0)=0$

Would I use the formula $a^{(1/n)}=R^{(1/n)}e^{(e^{i(alpha+2k(\pi))/n})}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no calculation needed. The family of solutions consists of linear combinations of $4$ functions. The initial conditions make all the constants $0$, so the solution is the identically $0$ function.

Another way of thinking about it is that the solution of the initial value problem is **unique**. But identically $0$ works, so it is the only solution.

Comment: Ok But how would I work that out to prove that...?

Comment: You can quote the uniqueness result, which has probably already been covered. If you want to do it the long long way, the characteristic equation has the triple root $0$, and a root of $1$. So the solutions are $A+Bx+Cx^2+De^x$. Now use the initial conditions to show that $A=B=C=D=0$. But that's too much work!

Comment: You are welcome. The question you were asked is a *conceptual* one. It can be solved by a calculation, but it follows immediately from knowledge of the nature of solutions of homogeneous linear DE with constant coefficients.

Comment: We went over the Characteristic Eqn. briefly earlier this semester. And I don't think I remembered because I was not so much of a fan of that particular concept.

Comment: It will be useful to become a fan. You are likely to be asked a question on the exam about it. And there are quite a number of applied settings where one needs it, specially in the second-order case.

Comment: Yes! Which is why I am trying to figure out a lot of this stuff now. I'm picking different homework problems that I have been working on.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so! In fact you should set an axillary equation regarding to the OE as $$m^4-m^3=0$$ and so solve it: $$m=0,~~~\text{3 times}~~~m=1$$ and then write the proper solution as $$y=C_1+C_2x+C_3x^2+C_4\text{e}^x$$ Now put the initial conditions. I don't think you get another one but the Andrea's one.

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks >8-).

Comment: Nice work, Babak!

Comment: @BabakS.:Excellent❁You are the best teacher ✓

Comment: @flashdesign2550: Manunam.:)

Comment: @BabakS.:(◕‿◕)khahesh mikonam.man mamnunam.